# Visual Editor for eclipse not associated with a class

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-editor

I create a class in visual editor.  I check it into subversion.  My coworker checks out the project.

Tries to open the class in visual editor but instead it just opens in the normal class dialog.  How can this class be associated with visual editor again?  How can I keep the associate alive in source control?

Coworker is able to create visual classes in the project that do associate it is just the classes that carry over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File associations are workspace dependent in Eclipse.

Check Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations to make sure that you both have Visual Editor as the default for the particular file extension.